# How to Read Json/Text Files from Asset Folder in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, mobile-development

I have a xamarin app where I need to read from a json file I have added in the Asset folder.

[This is how the folder tree is in the solution explorer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmtsG.png)

The code being used to read this json file is called from the User class in the Model folder.

This is how I have tried to access this file.

```
string path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "..", "Assets", "data", "User.json");
var assembly = typeof(User).GetType().Assembly;
var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"{assembly.GetName().Name}.{"User.json"}");
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    string jsonString = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(jsonString);
}
```

The stream variable is null.
Please help out.

Comment: Could it work ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First check that you have set `User.json` file to `Buid Action:EmbeddedResource`.

then do like below:

```
var assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(User)).Assembly;
Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("TravulRecd.Assets.data.User.json");
string jsonString = "";
using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
  {
     jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();
  }
```